# Select currently viewed slide for callback function in SlideJS plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, slideshow, slidesjs

I asked this question on the [plugin's forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/slidesjs/Select%2420current%2420slide/slidesjs/sVIsY9mV9tQ/V7tBRRuaDEQJ), but I think they are dead, no point. Maybe you can help me.

All I need to do is select the currently viewed slide element, so I can pop a caption over it with `.slideToggle()`. What I tried was

```
callback: {
             complete: function(number){
               $("#slides").find("slidesjs-index=\""+number+"\"").children(".cap").slideToggle();
            }
          }
```

But that returns a syntax error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: slidesjs-index="2"
```

Which I presume is because `slidesjs-index="(index of the automatically enumerated element)"` is not a valid HTML attribute, so the browser does not accept that script. Can you please suggest some method of selecting the current slide so I can call the callback function to pop the caption over the relevant image?

Is there maybe a way to just search inside the tag name for a matching string and select the element using that?

Comment: I'm not sure without digging into slidesjs. If you decide to just use a slideshow with captions already built in, I have one that would probably fit your needs: http://kthornbloom.com/smoothslides/

Comment: I need touch support for this one, so I can't use smoothslides unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with syntax:

```
slidesjs-index=\""+number+"\""
```

Is supposed to be

```
slidesjs\-index\=\""+number+"\""
```

Such that it's a string, not an expression. Adding escape characters fixed the problem.